# IBM MobileFirst Server Error When Deploying The Helloworld Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

MobileFirst Console LOG:

```
[2014-12-17 11:16:49]             Environment 'iPhone' was created. 
[2014-12-17 11:17:00]             Starting build process: application 'HelloWorldApp', environment 'iphone' 
[2014-12-17 11:17:13] FWLPL0010W: The current server configuration is set to "localhost". Therefore the MobileFirst build uses the primary IP address of this 
computer (192.168.137.1) instead. It is recommended to set the server configuration to use the fully qualified hostname or IP address 
of this computer. To configure the setting, in the "Servers" view double-click the MobileFirst Development Server entry and edit the 
"Host name" field. 
[2014-12-17 11:17:25]             Application 'HelloWorldApp' with environment 'iphone' build finished.
[2014-12-17 11:19:38]             Starting build process: application 'HelloWorldApp', all environments 
[2014-12-17 11:20:03]             Application 'HelloWorldApp' with all environments build finished.
[2014-12-17 11:20:03]             Deploying application 'HelloWorldApp' with all environments to MobileFirst Server... 
[2014-12-17 11:20:07]             Failed to deploy application 'HelloWorldApp' to MobileFirst Server: : HTTP 500 - Internal Server Errorr
```

MobileFirst Development Server Errorlog:

```
[ERROR   ] F:\Worklight%206.3\Workspace\rough\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
F:\Worklight%206.3\Workspace\rough\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] F:\Worklight%206.3\Workspace\rough\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
F:\Worklight%206.3\Workspace\rough\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
                                                                                                               ManagementServlet
                                                                                                               WorklightServices
                                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.wink.common.internal.i18n.Messages
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.initAlternateShortcutMap(DeploymentConfiguration.java:386)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.init(DeploymentConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getDeploymentConfiguration(RestServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
```

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the mobilefirstServerConfig folder from the eclipse workspace and try again.

Comment: Can u be more specific bec i wasn't able to find any folder named "mobilefirstServerConfig" i can only find "MobileFirst Development Server" folder in my workspace.

Comment: In your file system, navigate to the workspace folder you are using for eclipse.

Comment: "Failed to deploy application 'HelloWorldApp' to MobileFirst Server: please verify that the MobileFirst Server is started and reachable." Error in MobileFirst Console.

Comment: Delete the workspace and try again?

Comment: I deleted the complete workspace and now trying to create a new worklight project in that workspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67090/discussion-between-kawinesh-sk-and-idan-adar).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and I tried all solutions given in this post. Please post, if any one got the solution for this "HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 3):

Actually problem is with MobileFirst project class path just replace Java jre 1.8 to jre 1.7 and server started working properly. I think JDK 1.8 caused the problem of "HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error". Please do vote up if you find this thing useful.

Answer (score 3):

Delete *MobileFirstServerConfig* file which is located in your workspace.And restrat your eclipse.
Then the error won't come.
It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to hard code the ip address of the WL server instead of "localhost"
Click on server tab at the bottom of eclipse > Double click on "worklight Development server" > Host Name: "you Lan Ip address" instead of "localhost" and save the changes "Ctrl+s".
-Redeploy again.

Comment: Hi Sam, Your solution doesn't worked for me as I think there is something wrong with server configuration, but doing what you said will help some one who is not able to view application on browser using default "localhost". I hope you remember me mate :)

Comment: Hi Rohit :))) Of course I do, Thanks for providing your input on my answer. I will note your response as a reference. :)

Comment: Changed 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the Workspace folder should not contain spaces.
For Eg: Create a folder like "WorkSpace" .

"Work  Space"  will give you this error.